# Read JSON and append JSON key into url to fetch data

Tags: go

I am trying to fetch the JSON data from API and I am fetching those data and with that json data I need to craft URL by appending ID's value from json data to my URL so how should I do that below is the details.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/"
    token := ""
    bearer := "Bearer " + token

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, bytes.NewBuffer(nil))
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", bearer)
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}

    client.CheckRedirect = func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        for key, val := range via[0].Header {
            req.Header[key] = val
        }
        return err
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    src := []byte(data)
    dst := &bytes.Buffer{}
    if err := json.Indent(dst, src, "", "  "); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dst.String())

}
```

this gives me JSON data that i.e.

```
 {
    "id": 11657126,
    "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/groups/xxxxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxx ",
    "path": "xxxxxxxx",
    "description": "",
    "visibility": "private",
    "share_with_group_lock": false,
    "require_two_factor_authentication": false,
    "two_factor_grace_period": 48,
    "project_creation_level": "developer",
    "auto_devops_enabled": null,
    "subgroup_creation_level": "maintainer",
    "emails_disabled": null,
    "mentions_disabled": null,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "default_branch_protection": 2,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "request_access_enabled": true,
    "full_name": "xxxxxxxx",
    "full_path": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "created_at": "2021-04-09T06:58:53.390Z",
    "parent_id": xxxxxxxx,
    "ldap_cn": null,
    "ldap_access": null,
    "marked_for_deletion_on": null
  },
  {
    "id": 13064059,
    "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/groups/xxxxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "path": "xxxxx",
    "description": "",
    "visibility": "private",
    "share_with_group_lock": false,
    "require_two_factor_authentication": false,
    "two_factor_grace_period": 48,
    "project_creation_level": "developer",
    "auto_devops_enabled": null,
    "subgroup_creation_level": "maintainer",
    "emails_disabled": null,
    "mentions_disabled": null,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "default_branch_protection": 2,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "request_access_enabled": true,
    "full_name": "xxxxxx",
    "full_path": "xxxxxx",
    "created_at": "2021-08-18T03:13:26.121Z",
    "parent_id": 11656906,
    "ldap_cn": null,
    "ldap_access": null,
    "marked_for_deletion_on": null
  }
]
```

Now I need to use ID field from the json data to another API i.e.

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<ID>/projects?visibility=Public
```

so that I can fetch the data into bulk please help how should I do that in golang ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse json values. For Javascript;

```
var api = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/";
var apiEndpoint = "projects?visibility=";

function parseToJson(json){
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
  var idData = JSON.stringify(jsonData[0].id);
  var visibilityData = JSON.stringify(jsonData[0].visibility);
  var url= $`{api}{idData}{api}{apiEndpoint}`;
  
  // your http operation
 
}
```

By the way, here is the json parse process for Golang :

https://tutorialedge.net/golang/parsing-json-with-golang/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-parse-json-in-golang/

I hope that will be useful.